# How do I integrate PayPal Smart Button in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to integrate PayPal Smart buttons in my Laravel 8 Website. These are the documentation I am using:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/

https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK

**Issue:** I get two errors:

This error underlines the fetch in my front-end.

```
cart:278 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/createOrder 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

```
{err: "Error: Expected an order id to be passed↵
```

Here is my route file:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PayPalController;

Route::post('/createOrder', [PayPalController::class, 'createOrder']);
```

Here is my PayPalController Method:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

// To capture payment for paypal
namespace Sample\CaptureIntentExamples;

// Grabs the environment and request to be used for paypal
use Sample\PayPalClient;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersCreateRequest;

// Request/Response
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;


class PayPalController extends Controller
{
    public function createOrder() {

        $request = new OrdersCreateRequest();

        $request->prefer('return=representation');

        $request->body = [
            "intent" => "CAPTURE",
            "purchase_units" => [[
                "reference_id" => "test_ref_id1",
                "amount" => [
                    "value" => "100.00",
                    "currency_code" => "USD"
                    ]
            ]], 
            "application_context" => [
                "cancel_url" => "https://127.0.0.1:8000/cart",
                "return_url" => "https://127.0.0.1:8000/"
            ]         
        ];           

        // 3. Call PayPal to set up a transaction
        $client = PayPalClient::client();

        $response = $client->execute($request);

        // 4. Return a successful response to the client.
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Here is my front-end .blade.view file:

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=*******************"></script>
                                
<form action="/createOrder" method="POST">
@csrf   
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
                                
<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function() {
      return fetch('/createOrder', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'url': '/createOrder',
          "X-CSRF-Token": document.querySelector('input[name=_token]').value
         },
  }).then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
  }).then(function(data) {
    return data.orderID; // Use the same key name for order ID on the client and server
  });
  }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
</form>
```

I have edited the PayPalClient.php file with my credentials.

Comment: you may try the method of this link: https://5balloons.info/paypal-smart-button-integration-in-laravel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 500 error within your /createOrder route is something you'll need to diagnose/debug internally.  Try loading the URL in a browser and see if you get any more error output from Laravel. If you don't, edit the corresponding PHP to output more useful information about what's going on.

Once you sort that out and are returning an actual `id` as part of a JSON object, you need to change your front end code to read the key of that `id`. It looks like you are reading the key `orderID`, which won't be set unless you specifically set it.

The following front-end demo code is better, and has error handling: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

This part of your front-end code:

```
<form action="/createOrder" method="POST">
```

Makes absolutely no sense, unless it's just for testing purposes, but still really doesn't make sense.

All you should have is a container `<div>` with the id `paypal-button-container`, for the JS to render its own button in. That button does not in any way use or work with an HTML form.

Comment: I will give it a shot! I am gonna just rebuild the controller from scratch and see what happens.

Comment: I made sure to return it as return response()->json(['id' => $response->result->id]); and it works when tested. But now it gives me a 419 and Error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: The error means you are outputting things other than JSON. Don't do that.

Comment: How would I make sure it's in JSON instead of whatever other format its trying to grab?

Comment: Look at the response body in your browser's Dev Tools network tab, or load the createOrder URL directly in your browser, or use some tool like curl to do the request to your endpoint, and save the entire response body output.  It seems there will be be obvious things like HTML there that are not valid JSON. But if you are at all confused you can copy and paste your body into a JSON validator and watch it complain loudly about the wrong things your endpoint is returning that are not JSON. If you don't know what to do, research how to output just JSON from Laravel

Comment: So it seems when I load createOrder in the url it responds with json. But when it fetches it seems to freak out.

Comment: You wouldn't believe it if I said that I changed method: 'POST', to method: 'GET', and it works.

Comment: That really helped! I figured since for get it was grabbing json and post was grabbing html, I just switched out the methods and it worked!

Comment: On the backend you need to set up a route than properly handles POST (or both POST and GET) for it to do what's expected as far as POST.  Otherwise, it won't match the request and will revert to whatever your default is, such as a 404 or index.